# jquery history plugin

Tags: jquery, history, fragment-identifier, hashchange

I am using this plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

on this page:

http://www.crtaci.info/index.php?autocom=majice

I dont know why but it seems i cant figure out what to do to get this to work... Guess i need more sleep... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

railscasts has an episode regarding this topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/175-ajax-history-and-bookmarks

Answer (score 3):

I use the jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library.  It's simple, robust, and has a 
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

An alternative which I use is balupton's jQuery History which provides nice tracking of hash changes for your website. And jQuery Ajaxy which allows you to have a rich ajax website while still supporting the back and forward buttons and no server side changes.

jQuery History: http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-history

jQuery Ajaxy: http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy