# jQuery plugin for navigating a site using ajax calls instead of page loads?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I am looking for a documented, cross-browser supported jQuery plugin that I can use to build a site like this:
http://redsquareagency.com/

As you can see, as you navigate through the site, the URL changes via a hash and all new pages are loaded via ajax calls instead of page loads. This allows for some neat animations to be used when a new page is loaded.

I've searched for a while trying to find a good plugin that provides this functionality. The best I can find is jQuery Ajaxy: http://balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

But, the documentation is lacking, and I found it incompatible with the latest jQuery version (1.6.0).

Anyone know of plugins that can accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's available as a jQuery plugin (so I'm adding a comment instead of an answer) but you could look at SWFaddress - I used that on my own site which runs jQuery in parallel.

Comment: This needs to be done at application architecture level. You need a router which sends internal page content in response to ajax requests.

Comment: Looks like this was asked in a different form: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415291/jquery-history-plugin

Best ways to accomplish this:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html

http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

Personally, I'm going to go with jQuery BBQ for its documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm I don't think there is ONE plugin that does everything. But you can pretty much do some jquery your self with combination of [jquery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/).

What you do do is write some code make all your `hrefs` load via `AJAX`. Like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.history.init(loadContent);
            $('#navigation a').not('.external-link').click(function(e) {
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
                    $.history.load(url);
                    return false;
                });
        });
```

And that's it. The jquery history plugin will take care of the rest. You should also read [google's documentation](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) on how to do this properly for them to index it.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is [swfaddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/). It provides deep linking for flash and ajax sites (obviously your looking for the ajax feature). You basically just have to listen for a page change request and load content accordingly.

Comment: Does swfaddress have added weight to support communication with SWFs that I don't need?